# Keep Special Characters when parsing JSON response

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

I have retrieve this key/value from a hash using the facebook api

```
"message":"Next Practice:\n\nDate: 04.05.2014\nTime: 10:00-12:00\nVenue: Llandaff Fields\n\nAll welcome
```

but when i save it to my model i seem to lose all the special characters, i.e \n. Is there a way to save the value as it is returned so that i can use the \n when outputting to my view using .html_safe

This is how i am retrieving the data

```
def get_feed
  fb_access_token = access_token
  uri = URI(URI.escape "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?#{fb_access_token}")
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)
  formatted_data(results)  
end
```

anything i need to be doing to keep that string with \n left in it

Thanks

Comment: Did you try ? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-dump

Comment: What exactly happens to the `\n`? They become new-lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the following code:

```
raw_json = '{"message":"Next Practice:\n\nDate: 04.05.2014\nTime: 10:00-12:00\nVenue: Llandaff Fields\n\nAll welcome"}'
parsed_json = JSON.parse(raw_json)
puts parsed_json['message']
# => Next Practice:

# => Date: 04.05.2014
# => Time: 10:00-12:00
# => Venue: Llandaff Fields

# => All welcome
```

So the `\n` is kept (it is parsed, and shown as real new-line). I also don't believe that saving this to your model erased the new lines.

Where I think your *real* problem lies is that in HTML new lines (`\n`) are not rendered as new lines at all, but as spaces. To render them as new lines, you need to replace them with breaks (`<br>`).

So you can try using the following on your ERB:

```
<div class=message><%= feed.message.gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></div>
```

Your new-lines will now be rendered on the page.